# Can HP OpenView read app status data stored in SQL Table?

Tags: operations

I need to know if HP Operation Manger (formerly OpenView) can read application staus information from a table in SQL server database. Like I am storing the log data from SSIS (SQL Server Integration Services) package in a SQL table and I want this to be read by the Operations Management tool. My client is using HP OpenView/Operations Manager. I checked a lot of documents in HP site but still not sure if it can do this. OpenView looks like a mammoth software to me. Any OpenView experts there, please help.

PS:- Not sure if this has to be asked in ServerFault.

Answer (score 1):

You can try writing a BATCH to run the query on SQL and redirect the output to a flat file on the server and use Log File Monitoring Policy to read the content you require.

This is a workaround.

Actually I too am searching for a mechanism to read from the table directly!

Do let me know if u stumble upon something :)